# Error in Arraylist in c# 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, arraylist, c#-3.0

I have a array list

```
private ArrayList rps = new ArrayList();
```

now below code is working fine in 2005 but not in visual studio 2008

```
int min = Convert.ToInt32(rps.Item(0));
int max = Convert.ToInt32(rps.Item(rps.Count - 1));
```

> **Error:** System.Collections.ArrayList does not contain a definition for 'Item' and no extension method 'Item' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.ArrayList' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That code wouldn't work in VS 2005 either. Something similar might work in VB, but not in C#. The C# code would be:

```
int min = Convert.ToInt32(rps[0]);
int max = Convert.ToInt32(rps.Item[rps.Count - 1]);
```

However, I'd advise you to start using generic collections such as `List<T>` instead.

Comment: true, I have converted that from VB

Comment: Yep, first thing when I saw the code was wonder why the VB.NET was tagged with C#... till I saw the `;`.

Answer (score 3):

Use an [indexer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x16t2tx%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).

```
int min = Convert.ToInt32(rps[0]);
```

Also consider using `List<T>` instead of `ArrayList`.

Answer (score 2):

You have a syntax error:

```
rps.Item(0)
```

Should be:

```
rps[0]
```

Note - you really shouldn't be using `ArrayList` - it predates generics which is what you *should* be using instead.